# How to double all words of latin letters in the string with sed?

Tags: string, sed, cpu-word

I was trying to double all latin words in the string, actually we also need to put it in brackets. ("lol" -> "(lollol)")
"Word" here means the sequence of latin letters (**[A-Za-z]\+**). I was trying a lot, like:

1) **ls -l /bin | sed "s/[^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*/(&&)/g"**, but it is doubling all symbolls even with special symbols and digits

2) Also i have an idea to take all nonsuitable words in '|' brackets:
 (**ls -l /bin | sed "s/[^ ]*[^A-Za-z ][^ ]*/|&|/g"**) and then double all words without brackets (wasn`t still thinking how) and remove '|' brackets. I realize that it is not effective to use 3 sed commands and that there may be '|' symbol in the sequence(though i know how to solve this problem).

So after few days of struggle i've decided to take some help.

Here are some examples:

1)"rwx" - > "(rwxrwx)"

2) "-rwx" - > "-rwx"

3)"jk2l" - > "jk2l"

4)"jkl" - > "(jkljkl)"

Now string examples:

1) "I want 2 sh-w" - > "(II) (wantwant) 2 sh-w"

2) "-rwx but th1-s" - > "-rwx (butbut) th1-s"

Comment: Does this give the desired output?  `echo 'one! two #three' | sed 's/[A-Za-z]\+/(&&)/g'`  If not, update your question to explain why and give a variety of inputs with their expected output.

Comment: @jas , no. "-rwx" -> "-(rwxrwx)", but it must be "-rwx" -> "-rwx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(^|\s)([[:alpha:]]+)(\s|$)/\1(\2\2)\3/g;ta' file
```

This matches on words that only contain alpha characters and replaces them in the desired style then repeats the match again so as to pick up any missed matches in the first pass.

Comment: Thanks so much, you wouldn't believe how ironic it is. I`ve done about the same few hours ago. Nonetheless, your answer is GREAT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest awk for this task:

```
$ cat file
rwx
-rwx
jk2l
jkl
I want 2 sh-w
-rwx but th1-s

$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/) $i = "(" $i $i ")" }1' file
(rwxrwx)
-rwx
jk2l
(jkljkl)
(II) (wantwant) 2 sh-w
-rwx (butbut) th1-s
```